# Export to Excel from Crystal Reports without page headers/footers

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Just wondering if anybody had working code example (in c#) for exporting a crystal report to Excel from a .NET application without the report's page headers and footer's.

I am using crystal reports v9 runtime.

Comment: if you need a answer, i spend a bounty...?

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this you actually need to do it in the Crystal Report. My recommendation is to add a parameter to it, and then edit the header and footer suppress formulas to check the parameter. That was how we accomplished it. If there is way to do it from your code I would be interested in knowing it also.

Good luck!

Comment: There is not need to add a parameter, you can suppress the header and footer programatically before exporting.

Comment: I know it's been a while, but how do you suggest doing it? I am trying to do exactly that, but can't figure out how to translate it to code...

Comment: @K09P Sorry I could not tell you, it has been several years since I touched Crystal Reports.

Comment: I imagined you couldn't, but it was worth trying. Actually I ended up finding another way to do it. But thanks anyways :)

Comment: No need of parameter, there is pseudo-function PageNumber. Just use "PageNumber > 1" as Suppress condition for the header.

Answer (score 1):

Here my extension method for ReportDocument to supress all headers/footers. I use it for Excel export.

```
/// <summary>
/// Clears header/footer.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="rpt">The reportdocument</param>
public static void ClearReportHeaderAndFooter(this ReportDocument rpt)
{
    foreach (Section section in rpt.ReportDefinition.Sections)
    {
        if (section.Kind == AreaSectionKind.ReportHeader || section.Kind == AreaSectionKind.ReportFooter || section.Kind == AreaSectionKind.PageFooter || section.Kind == AreaSectionKind.PageHeader)
        {
            section.SectionFormat.EnableSuppress = true;
            section.SectionFormat.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
            foreach (var repO in section.ReportObjects)
            {
                if (repO is ReportObject)
                {
                    var reportObject = repO as ReportObject;
                    reportObject.ObjectFormat.EnableSuppress = true;

                    reportObject.Border.BorderColor = Color.White;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
myReportDocument.ClearReportHeaderAndFooter();
```